# Limit # of selectable items jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

As the title says, I'm trying to limit the number of selectable items in a certain list but searching SO where I found that I had to add this line to my code didnt do the trick:

```
if ($(".ui-selected, .ui-selecting").length > 4) {
   $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
 }
```

My code does differ a little from their codes so maybe I'm implementing it wrong but below is my (working) code. So what I'm trying to archieve here is that all selectable items should be disabled as soon as the var *total* reaches a certain value (for instance 5). When the value of 5 is reached no more items should be selectable but yet remain deselectable. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ut1pgxcg/

Javascript:

```
$( "#selectable" ).bind( "mousedown", function ( e ) {
    e.metaKey = true;
    } ).selectable({
        filter: "li:not(.taken)",
      stop: function() {
        var result = [];
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                result.push($(this).data('price'));
        });

        var sum = result.length;

          $( "#select-result" ).html(sum);

        var total = 0;
        $.each(result,function() {
            total += this;
        });

         $( "#price-result" ).html(total);                  
      }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<span>You selected:</span> <span id="select-result">0</span> slots, costing you +- $<span id="price-result">0</span>

<ol id="selectable">
<li class="raffle-slot" data-price="2">1</li>
<li class="raffle-slot taken" data-price="2">2</li>
<li class="raffle-slot" data-price="2">3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Add the relevant HTML please.

Comment: to add on the zakaria's comment, you should put a working version of your sample in codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Both done, see edited post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your code could be simplified a bit. See https://jsfiddle.net/u9z8t74u/

```
var total = 0;
var selectedCount = 0;
var threshold = 6;

$( "#selectable>li.raffle-slot:not('.taken')" ).bind( "click", function ( e ) {
    var price = $(this).data('price');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            total = total - price;
            selectedCount--;
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
    else if (price + total <= threshold) {
            total = total + price;
            selectedCount++;
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
    $('#select-result').html(selectedCount);
    $('#price-result').html(total);
});
```

The global vars could be absorbed within a closure, but this is a quick and dirty fix that takes a simpler approach, IMO.